# Monitor Object Creation using ASM in Java

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM to monitor Object creation in Java. Currently, I take the call to **init** as the indicator of the creation of a new object and instrument a program from

```
invoke XXX.init
```

to

```
dup;  
invoke XXX.init;  
call_my_method(Object)
```

My idea is to duplicate a copy of newObjectReference and, after the **init** of this object, I call my method to keep this object.

However, during runtime, there is an exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError, Expecting to find unitialized object on stack.
```

When I used "-noverify" option, during runtime, if there is a thread instance, a second exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
at test.ThreadTest.test
```

For the second case, I am sure there is no call to **start**() of a thread except that in the original program.

Is there a better way to monitor the New Object Creation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am assuming you can't use a memory profiler to monitor allocations.  Once you have this data you need a way of visualising it as well. e.g. http://www.yourkit.com/docs/11/help/allocations.jsp

Comment: can you provide the exact bytecode instruction you are using for `call_my_method(Object)`?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I made a mistake. I have assumed that the only argument of 'init' is the newly created object, so using 'dup' can visit this object after 'init'. However, I found that, right before the 'init', there might be some other object that is the argument used to 'initialize' the newly created object. That is why I got above two exceptions. This can be verified in the bytecode of 'Thread t= new Thread(new ARunnableClass())' or other similar object creation methods. I need to find some alternative ways to monitor the object creation.

Answer (score 4):

Try, converting invoke XXX.init to

`invoke XXX.init;

dup;

call_my_method(Object)`

Basically call the duplicate after the init method returns.

Explanation:: So given that you want to track new object creations, i am guessing you are looking at statements such as, **new XXX()**. Now, the way this translates to bytecode is as follows:-

`NEW XXX

DUP

INVOKESPECIAL <init>`

In other words, the **NEW** bytecode instruction is used to create the object itself. It is duplicated on top of the stack, so you have an additional copy of the object. At this point mind you, the 2 copies of the object are uninitialized. And then the init method is invoked on the first uninitialized object on top of the stack. By the time the constructor returns, the object is initialized, and thus the object sitting on top of the stack, is also initialized. (that is because the "object" sitting on top of the stack, is really an object reference pointing to the actual object which is sitting somewhere on the heap. I use the word object instead of object reference as it is simpler to explain things. sorry if this caused any confusion.)

Comment: Thank you again. I also found this to be a possible way though there some unmatched    'init' to    'new'. My another thought is to monitor 'Object.init' as it is possible that the initialization of each new object will invoke the 'init' of     'Object'.

Comment: yup... tracking Object.<init> is actually a smart way to go about it.. thanks for sharing :) Also, if you find a working solution, do post it here. thanks again :)